Handling very long import path
I need to patch a test method and have a path that so long that it goes above E501 80 symbols limit. Change of package name is not possible due dependencies elsewhere.
A sample of the problem:
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestSomething:
    @patch(
        "someveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongpath.to.a.method"
    )
    def test_something(self, mock_method): ...


Using f-string beforehand like this:
import someveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongpath as svl
imp_path = f"{svl.__name__}.to.a.method"

class TestSomething:
    @patch(imp_path)
    def test_something(self, mock_method): ...

fails, too.
A code sample to reproduce the problem:
from unittest.mock import patch
import matplotlib as mpl

imp_path = f"{mpl.__name__}.pyplot"


@patch(imp_path)
def qwe(mock_path):
    mock_path.plot([1, 2, 3])
    mock_path.show()
    mock_path.savefig()


qwe()


Any idea would be appreciated.

It does not "fail", it just gives a linter warning. You can just suppress the warning in this case (refer to your linter on how to suppress the warning in a specific line).

Well, I wrote word fail for the solution I tried to give, while linter sure is only warning. Suppressing warnings will not make already messy and huge package more readable. My task is bringing in better coding practices, not suppressing warnings.

To quote pep8: "However, know when to be inconsistent – sometimes style guide recommendations just aren’t applicable". I consider this such a case.
